# what's wrong with mongoose populate with match?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to populate a field with the match in mongoose but it does not return anything.

Code:

```
// provided in Mongoose document.
    Story.
      find(...).
      populate({
        path: 'fans',
        match: { age: { $gte: 21 }},
        select: 'name -_id',
        options: { limit: 5 }
      }).
      exec();
```

my mongoose version is:-  "mongoose": "^4.13.12"
real code:-

```
let populateQuery = [{
        path: 'service',
        select: 'name pricessss'
    match: { name: { $eq: 'someting' }}
    }, {
        path: 'job',
        select: 'appliedUser'
    }];

models.Project.find()
                    .populate(populateQuery)
                    .exec((err, projects) =>{})
```

o/p:- In projects.job the populated data is there but on projects.service it's returning null

Comment: What is your data? Which mongoose version do you use? Can you show us real code?

Comment: my mongoose version is :-  "mongoose": "^4.13.12" .  
my Code:-   
let populateQuery = [{
        path: 'service',
        select: 'name pricessss'
 match: { name: { $eq: 'someting' }}
    }, {
        path: 'job',
        select: 'appliedUser'
    }];

models.Project.find()
                    .populate(populateQuery)
                    .exec((err, projects) =>{})

Comment: Can you show us the data?

Comment: In projects.job I am getting the data but on projects.service it's null.